# how to get different values from an array?

Tags: javascript, php, json, codeigniter

I am sending some encoded data into an array and trying to retrieve them. i am using following code for that

```
var holiday_list =<?php echo json_encode($calendar_results); ?>;

        var events = []; //The events array

        $.each(holiday_list, function(key, value) {
            events.push({
                title: value.type, //get the type(am or pm)
                start: value.date_cal, //date of the calendar
                // className: "fc-event-skin22"

            });
```

There are two types. am and pm. i want to get all am results into one variable and all pm results into one variable. If anyone knows how to do that give me an idea. I am using php codeigniter framework. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You will need to show what values *value.type* contains, is it literally `'am'` and `'pm'`?

Comment: You could use a simple if condition to check wether value.type is am or pm and push that into a seperate array

Comment: It would be nice if you could post your $calender_results .

Comment: Post the value of `holiday_list`

Comment: @RobG yes. am and pm

Comment: @HarigovindR I did that. but it didn't work cz  i am generation a calendar below. It doesn't take in simple if codition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need a "if-else". Hope it will work.

```
        var amEvents = []; //The events array
        var  pmEvents = [];
        $.each(holiday_list, function(key, value) {
           if( value.type == 'am'){
               amEvents.push({
                title: value.type, //get the type(am or pm)
                start: value.date_cal, //date of the calendar
                // className: "fc-event-skin22"

               });

            }
            else{
                pmEvents.push({
                title: value.type, //get the type(am or pm)
                start: value.date_cal, //date of the calendar
                // className: "fc-event-skin22"

               });

             }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help you

```
var result;
for( var i = 0, len = holiday_list.length; i < len; i++ ) {
    if( holiday_list[i][title] == 'am' ) {
        result_am[] = holiday_list[i]['start']; 
    }
    else {
        result_pm[] = holiday_list[i]['start']; 
    }        
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can setup the arrays as properties of an object, then assign them based on the type:

```
var amTypes = [];
var pmTypes = [];
var types = {am:amTypes, pm:pmTypes};

$.each(holiday_list, function(key, value) {
  types[value.type].push({
    title: value.type,
    start: value.date_cal
  });
});
```

*amTypes* and *types.am* reference the same array, as for *pmTypes* and *types.pm*.

Untested since you haven't provided an sample data.